# Error PLSQL copying content of 2 tables in 1 with varray

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, cursor, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this tables:

```
CREATE TABLE departments (
dep_na  number(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
dname  VARCHAR2(15), 
loc      VARCHAR2(15)
);
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (20,'CONTABILITY','SEVILLA');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES (30,'INVEST','MADRID');
COMMIT;
CREATE TABLE employees (
emp_nu    number(4)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
surname  VARCHAR2(10),
oficio    VARCHAR2(10),
dir       number(4),
date_a DATE      ,
salar   number(6,2),
comis  number(6,2),
dep_na   number(2) NOT NULL REFERENCES departments(dept_no)
);
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY';
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (7369,'SANCHEZ','EMPLEADO',7902,'17/12/1990',1040,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (7499,'ARROYO','VENDEDOR',7698,'20/02/1990',1500,390,30);
COMMIT;

create or replace
TYPE TDEP AS OBJECT(
dep_na NUMBER(2),
dname VARCHAR2(15),
loc VARCHAR2(15)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEMPLE AS OBJECT(
emp_nu    number(4),
surname  VARCHAR2(10),
oficio    VARCHAR2(10),
dir       number(4),
date_a DATE,
salar   number(6,2),
comision  number(6,2),
dep_na   TDEP
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VEMPLE AS VARRAY(20) OF TEMPLE;
```

I created the following table pack with varray and types, but I have the problem that when I insert the contents of the employees and departments tables in the table pack the computer gives me error.

```
CREATE TABLE pack(
array_employees VEMPLE,
departme TDEP
);
```

I have problems with this code:

```
DECLARE
T VEMPLE;
A TDEP
CURSOR C1 is select * from departamentos order by dep_na;
CURSOR C2(DEPAR NUMBER) is select * from empleados where dep_na = depar;
j integer := 1;
BEGIN
for i in C1 LOOP 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.dep_na);
  T := NEW VEMPLE();
  A := NEW TDEP();
  j := 1;
  for x in C2(i.dep_na) loop
    if j < T.LIMIT THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x.apellido || ' - ' || i.dep_na);
      T.extend;
      T(j) := NEW TEMPLE(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      T(j).departments := NEW TDEP(i.loc, NULL, NULL);
      j := j + 1;
    end if;
end loop;
INSERT INTO Grupos VALUES(i.A, T);
end loop;
end;
/
```

I need help with this query in Oracle. I have problems with the cursor.

Comment: Might be helpful to include the error you get. You're missing a semicolon after `A TDEP`, is that all it's complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you're just missing a semicolon after `A TDEP` in the declare section, which is causing your `ORA-06550: line 4, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CURSOR" when expecting ...` error. Which you haven't shown, but you said it's a cursor error, so that seems to line up.

But you have lots of other errors, some from inconsistent naming which I think is from partially changing things for posting, but partly from how you're creating object instances. I think this is pretty much clean:

```
DECLARE
T VEMPLE;
A TDEP;
CURSOR C1 is select * from departments order by dep_na;
CURSOR C2(DEPAR NUMBER) is select * from employees where dep_na = depar;
j integer := 1;
BEGIN
for i in C1 LOOP 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.dep_na);
  T := NEW VEMPLE();
  -- supply values to constructor
  A := NEW TDEP(i.dep_na, i.dname, i.loc);
  j := 1;
  for x in C2(i.dep_na) loop
    if j < T.LIMIT THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x.surname|| ' - ' || i.dep_na);
      T.extend;
      -- supply values to constructor
      T(j) := NEW TEMPLE(x.emp_nu, x.surname, x.oficio,
        x.dir, x.date_a, x.salar, x.comis, A);
      -- no idea what the next line is doing
      -- T(j).departments := NEW TDEP(i.loc, NULL, NULL);
      j := j + 1;
    end if;
end loop;
-- elements were wrong way round, which wouldn't matter if you
-- included the column names - which is good practice anyway
INSERT INTO pack VALUES(T, A);
end loop;
end;
/
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6cef8/1). (Don't try to select from the table in the Fiddle though, it struggles with object types; this just shows it doesn't error...)

I assume this is an exercise. There are probably better and more efficient ways to convert from a relational to an object schema.

Comment: Thank you very much!, Alex Poole